# Creating a Hive table automatically changes charset settings of mysql metastore

Tags: mysql, hadoop, integration, hive, meta

I configured Hive to use a mysql metastore. It works fine.

But when I try to drop a table, I get some errors like below.

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error(s) were found while auto-creating/validating the datastore for classes. The errors are printed in the log, and are attached to this exception.
NestedThrowables:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I did some research, google and [official faq](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/faq.html) tell me that changing mysql character set settings will fix this.

My mysql settings as below

```
mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                  |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                   |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                   |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I changed all character set settings from `utf8` to `latin1`, except `character_set_filesystem`, `character_set_system`, `character_sets_dir`.

Even do so, I still get the same errors when I try to drop tables.
And worse, whenever I create a new table, the mysql character set settings will be reset to `utf-8`.

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 5):

the problem is that in hive-site.xml it use an other database in creation 'hive' in the bellow

```
 <property>
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
 <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
 </property>
```

change the database name to 'metastore' that you hade already create in mysql like this

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
```

hope that this regle the problem I had the same problem and I fixed it like this.
freindly Matouk